# find a homotopy between $a^{-1}*a$ and $k$

Tags: general-topology

$k$ is the identity element in the fundamental group, i.e $\forall a\in L(X,x_0), a*k=k*a=a$

Note that $a^{-1} (r)=a(1-r)$ so

$$(a^{-1}*a)(r)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         a(2(1-r)-1) & \mbox{if $0 \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2} $};\\
        a(2r-1) & \mbox{if $\frac{1}{2} \leq r \leq 1$}.\end{array} \right.$$

Let  $H': X×[0,1] \to X $ be defined by 
$$H' (r,s)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         a((2(1-r)-1)(1-s)) & \mbox{if $0 \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2} $};\\
        a((2r-1)(1-s)) & \mbox{if $\frac{1}{2} \leq r \leq 1$}.\end{array} \right.$$

we have $H'$ continuous by the Gluing lemma. We also check when $s=0$ and $s=1$ and obtain 
$$H' (r,0)=(a^{-1}*a)(r)$$
And 
$$H' (r,1)
=k(r)$$
So
$$a^{-1}*a∼k$$

I feel like I made mistake on the definition of $(a^{-1}*a)(r)$ but I don't know hwo to fix it. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: No, your definition is correct. Write instead $a^{-1}(2r)$, it is easier to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do the other part, that is, $a*a^{-1}∼k$ in a different way, which I think is much easier to look at.

Now,
$$
a*a^{-1} = a \circ g 
$$
where $g: I \rightarrow I$ is defined
$$
g(r)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         2r & \mbox{if $0 \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2} $};\\
        2-2r & \mbox{if $\frac{1}{2} \leq r \leq 1$}.\end{array} \right.
$$
Let $g'$ be another function with  $ \quad g'(r) = 0, \quad 0 \leq r \leq 1$.

It is easy to see that $g ∼ g'$. It follows,  $a*a^{-1} = a \circ g ∼ a \circ g' = k$